# Does UML shared aggregation imply absence of cycles?

Tags: language-lawyer, uml, aggregation, class-diagram

## In short

Shared aggregation seems to express nothing more than a simple association. It is apparently a "modeling placebo" with no objective reason to use it (except in specific contexts where modelers have agreed between them on specific additional semantic).

Several sources claim however that shared aggregation would imply absence of cycles in the aggregation graph of instances.  This would make aggregation a powerful tool in the domain of graph modeling.

But I couldn't find any evidence of those claims in the specifications.  Did I miss some indirect evidence (e.g. interplay of several constraints)?

## More details

### The quote

In their book ***The Unified Modeling Language Reference Manual, 2nd Edition***, Booch, Jacobson and Rumbaugh claim about (shared) aggregation:

> The distinction between aggregation and association is often a matter of taste rather than a difference in semantics. Keep in mind that aggregation is association. Aggregation conveys the thought that the aggregate is inherently the sum of its parts. In fact, the only real semantics that it adds to association is the ***constraint that chains of aggregate links may not form cycles***, which is often important to know, however. (...) In spite of the few semantics attached to aggregation, everybody thinks it is necessary (for different reasons). Think of it as a modeling placebo.

Other rather well informed sources(e.g. [uml-diagrams.org](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/aggregation.html) and several academic papers) keep the directed acyclic graph for granted as well.

### Verification against the UML specifications

The books is from 2004, based on UML 2.0. But most of this claim is still verified in the ***UML 2.5.1 specification***.  Shared aggregation is defined therein in very vague terms and without any objective advantage over a simple association (p.112):

> Sometimes a Property is used to model circumstances in which one instance is used to group together a set of instances; this is called aggregation. To represent such circumstances, a Property has an aggregation property, of type AggregationKind; (...)
> ...
> shared :
> Indicates that the Property has shared aggregation semantics. Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler.

Another clause about aggregation prevents some special cycling situations (p.200):

> An end Property of an Association may only be marked as a shared or composite aggregation if the Association is binary and the other end is not marked as a shared or composite aggregation.

I have however not found any evidence that "*chains of aggregate links may not form cycles*" in the general case. I also did not find other properties such as transitivity and anti-symetry which could allow to infer the absence of cycles.

Is the claim by the UML inventors now obsolete?  Or did I miss something in the current specs that would allow to derive this statement ?

Comment: I have to look into that, but from memory composition equals responsibility and that would exclude a cycle.

Comment: Btw. speaking of aggregation is incorrect. You mean composite aggregation? Shared aggregation doesn't even have a semantic. The wording taken from the book you cite might be out of date.

Comment: @qwerty_so I meant shared aggregation.  I've corrected except for the quote: Booch et al use "aggregation" for shared aggregation and "composition".  Indeed,  for composition it can be inferred from the lifecycle responsibilities (and it's even black on white "Compositions may be linked in a directed acyclic graph with transitive deletion characteristics".   If the statement would still be true for shared aggregation, there would finally be a justified use of it, to model trees and other DAGs with reflexive associations as in this [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70313142/3723423)

Comment: The only constraint for shared aggregation is that it can only be used on binary associations.

Comment: What kind of evidence would you find if you were to find it?  In practice, if an aggregate is the sum of its parts then how could a cycle be possible?

Comment: That book goes only up to UML 2.0, not 2.5. See my notes in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70313142/how-to-understand-the-reflexive-aggregation-relationship-similar-to-reflexive

Comment: The UML 2.5.1 spec page 112 says "Compositions may be linked in a directed acyclic graph".  So are you asking why there is no similar statement about cycles with regards to shared aggregation?

Comment: @DaveS Yes. For composition it is indeed very clear.  The part whole relationship and the exclusive ownership allow to deduce a DAG. For the shared aggregation, it's a different story.  In fact it seems to have no added value compared to a simple association. The only authoritative argument in its favour is this quote that implies that shared aggregation would imply a DAG at the instance level.  In this case,  it could have an advantage in some instances.  I've looked at constraints and found none relevant.  i wonder if there's a subtle interplay between several constraints that I missed.

Comment: This popular [UML site](https://www.uml-diagrams.org/aggregation.html) alo makes a claim about DAG for shared aggregation.

Comment: Yes, the graph should be acyclic at the instance level and not necessarily at the class level.  But I don't understand why it seems to have no added value compared to simple association.  The spec says, "Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler".  As a modeler, association and shared aggregation give me different ways to represent relationships, even if the precise semantics of the difference are left up to me.  I can use them to convey a specific intent for implementation details like lifecycle.

Comment: @DaveS I understand your concern. I'm a bit provocative on that, probably because I was myself so convinced of the objective need for shared aggregation and ended up to realise how subjective it was. Indeed, if you as a modeler decide some semantics and if it helps you, it's fine.  But if a different modeler reads your diagram with a different understanding,  it may lead to ambiguity and misunderstandings.  I also witnessed groups of modelers loosing an awful lot of time debating on simple association vs. their understanding of aggregation. ...

Comment: this is why, I like to stress that it's not worth the debate if there is no clear an "Unified" understanding of when to use aggregation vs. association.    Finally,  it creates a lot of confusion, when people implement the models, when they realize they implement an association but on the diagram there's an aggregation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your analysis is correct. UML 2 doesn't give shared aggregation any semantics.

#### However

The UML 1 said:

> Both kinds of aggregations define a transitive, antisymmetric relationship (i.e., the instances form a directed, non-cyclic graph).

I don't know, why this was not taken over to UML 2. I can only speculate that it was a case of throwing the baby out with the bath water. Some people wanted to make it absolutely clear, that the specification leaves the semantics of shared aggregation open for domain specific interpretation. And they forgot that it in fact was meant to have some, however weak, semantics.

#### My take on that

Our situation is this: A whole lot of books and websites on the subject, the UML 1 specification and common sense agree, that a whole-part relationship, whether shared or composite, is acyclic. UML 2 is silent on the subject.

Therefore, I for my part will interpret shared aggregation as acyclic. Of course, I would document this interpretation in a modeling guideline. However, I don't expect that it will confuse a lot of readers of my diagrams, even if they didn't read my guideline, since it corresponds to what they would expect anyway.

As a final note: Don't use aggregation unless you really need to. In my experience it causes a lot of unnecessary discussions.

Comment: Indeed,  UML 1.4, section 2.5.4.1 tells inter alia:  "An association may represent an aggregation; that is, a whole/part relationship.(...) A shareable aggregation denotes weak ownership (...)  Both kinds of aggregations define a transitive, antisymmetric relationship; that is, the instances form a directed, non-cyclic graph".  The transitive and antisymetric properties can e derived from the principle of the whole/part relationship (i.e. an instance cannot be part of itself, but the parts of are parts are indirectly also parts).

Comment: I believe that this loss is not an accident, but a deliberate relaxing of rules to accommodate different practices that emerged over time, some of which being incompatible with the absence of cycles.  I think in particular of the all too frequent (and formally unjustified) usage of shared aggregation to represent [object composition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition) opposed to inheritance.

Answer (score 1):

I think my favorite page 110 of UML 2.5 is quite clear about this:

> Sometimes a Property is used to model circumstances in which one instance is used to group together a set of instances; this is called aggregation. To represent such circumstances, a Property has an aggregation property, of type AggregationKind; the instance representing the whole group is classified by the owner of the Property, and the instances representing the grouped individuals are classified by the type of the Property. AggregationKind is an enumeration with the following literal values:
>
> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | none | Indicates that the Property has no aggregation semantics. |
> | shared | Indicates that the Property has shared aggregation semantics. **Precise semantics of shared aggregation varies by application area and modeler.** |
> | composite | Indicates that the Property is aggregated compositely, i.e., the composite object has responsibility for the existence and storage of the composed objects (see the definition of parts in 11.2.3). |
>
> Composite aggregation is a strong form of aggregation that requires a part object be included in **at most one composite** object at a time. If a composite object is deleted, all of its part instances that are objects are deleted with it.

Emphasis by me. Shared aggregation is out of the run in any case since its semantic is undefined by definition. So the implication is only for composite aggregation.

---

**What is the standard?**

UML has quite some history. And there are lots of citations out there. Only the fewest get updates along with UML evolving. Although Booch et al. invented UML, they are no longer defining the standard. That's done by OMG and they publish the ISO standard (for which you can pay extra money if you like). Quite some terms go round  which have ancient origins and are outdated the one or other way. Still, they are being used - and in the now wrong context.

**Is the standard perfect?**

Definitely not. It's evolving and still has quite some flaws or misconceptions. In my opinion the introduction of shared aggregation in UML 2.0 was not a so good idea. To define something that has no definition per definition seems odd. And looking at the confusion about this concept proves me right.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  But I'm looking exactly at shared aggregation to find out if there is some hidden value in it that could be relevant for very specific cases.  The fact that the specs do not define precise semantics does not mean that there is no semantic at all, nor that there are no constraints.  We know for example that shared aggregation is only allowed for binary associations, and that shared aggregation on one side of an association implies absence of shared or composite aggregation at the other end (p.200).

Comment: Moreover, in addition to the book  (which was written by the three inventors of UML) , I found several other places (e.g. https://www.uml-diagrams.org/aggregation.html, as well as several academic papers) where a DAG for shared aggregation was assumed, as well as asymetry and transitivity.  uml-diagrams even claims on this base that if there is an aggregation between 2 classes, there cannot be a different aggregation in the opposite direction.  This makes me think that I might have missed something.

Comment: Well, Daimler and Benz invented the automobile, but they would not be able to repair one of the modern descendants. OMG defines the standard, not the inventors. uml-diagrams just cites the inventor's book, not OMG. Finally there's certainly no interpretation for that "it has no semantics".

Comment: I sometimes wonder what driving a car would look like, if the OMG would have made automotive standards: "Conformant cars should have a blinker.  The blinker command should be fixed to the right of the steering wheel and bear the hollow blinker symbol.  The exact semantic of blinking and the way the blinker command shall be operated to trigger the left or the right signal is purposely left unspecified."  ;-)

Comment: They probably would have added a left/right steering option as well as a middle steering. Just in case...