# Relation between Address class and Person class in a Class Diagram?

Tags: uml, associations, relationship, class-diagram

I am making a class diagram. I have a `Person` class and an `Address` class. I am thinking there is a '*Has-A*' relation between the `Person` class and `Address` class (Aggregation):

1. **Am I right in marking the relationship as association?**
2. Does it depend on us how we want the model the relationship?
   For example, if I have two classes, `Book` and `Library`, I could say that `Books` shall not exist without a `Library` (composition) or I could say that `Books` may exist independent of library(Aggregation).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between association, aggregation and composition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/885937/what-is-the-difference-between-association-aggregation-and-composition)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Is the association right?

Yes, you are right:  a simple association expresses perfectly that a `Person` has an `Address`.  Nobody could claim on the base of your narrative that your model would be wrong.

But modeling is a form of communication: You may well chose a different **notation** to add nuance in what you express, and you may decide for different **semantics** to tell how you see things in view of your needs.

### Does it depend on us? Notation

In our example, you may want to clarify what you mean with the association by giving it a name:
[image]

Or you may prefer to clarify the role of the address in the association:
[image: String]

Or in complex diagrams you may prefer the shorter but equivalent property notation, nevertheless keeping in mind that "*A useful convention for general modeling scenarios is that a Property whose type is a kind of Class is an Association end, while a property whose type is a kind of DataType is not*":

[image]

### Does it depend on us? Semantics

You could go for aggregation, but I'd strongly discourage it since UML does not define any semantic for it. So there's no benefit compared to a simple association.

You could consider composition. It might in general not be the best choice, as addresses exist independently of the persons. But in an application that creates separate `Address` objects for each `Person`, it could reveal how you intend to manage addresses.

Or you may want some richer semantics, for example with an association class to tell that people could have plenty of addresses of different kinds:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

1. There is no one correct answer. There are many valid ways to model a scenario. In this case you could either mark the relationship between Person and Address as an association (more specifically aggregation), or you could mark it as a complex attribute.
2. Yes, details like that should be discussed with stakeholders / people who understand the domain you are modelling.

Comment: True! And it also depends on the purpose of the class diagram. Is it a real world model? Is it a functional application design? Is it a database design? Is it a Java or C# class design? If it is a real world model, then an address shall not be aggregated under person. My address is not a part of me.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl I’ confused by your last remark. Is there any quote in the UML specs that gives a part-whole semantic to a shared aggregation?

Comment: @Christophe:  No, but the meaning of the word 'aggregation' in English implies that  items are put together to form some kind of group (the aggregate). I don't think that in the real world, you would say that a person is an aggregation of an address and other things and therefore, I think you shall not model address aggregated under person in a real world model.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl I think we agree. It’s just that I’d even go further and always avoid shared aggregation, since  doesn’t add anything useful (https://stackoverflow.com/q/70316119/3723423)