# What is a Unary association in UML

Tags: uml, associations, class-diagram

While I googled to understand the Unary associations, I got the following two explanations:

**the first is:**

> A unary relationship is when both participants in the relationship are
> the same entity. For Example: Subjects may be prerequisites for other
> subjects, or one employee manages many Employees.

**and the second is:**

> Class B knows about ClassA.
>
> Class A does not know about ClassB.
>
> Now lets look at the following example:
>
> You can see the Person and Address relationship below. We call this
> relationship as has-a relationship since person has a address. So
> Person knows the address but address does not know anything about
> person

Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: You second explanation is not related at all to unary associations.

Comment: @GeertBellekens , Thank you for your comment. I saw several slideShare and youtube videos that explain the Unary associations using the second explanation, So that make me really confused.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BhEoV57nj0Q&t=308s

Comment: Definition of unary: **having, consisting of, or acting on a single element, item, or component** So this is clearly about associations that only involve a single element. Not be to confused with **Unidirectional**

Comment: Associations in UML are binary or n-ary. What would be a unary association? A connecrtor to nothing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Common language

The [**arity**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arity) of an association is about how many classes are associated. This is an ambiguous concept since some understand different classes, whereas others understand instances.

When applied to **unary**, the first interpretation would mean reflexive association (or self-association,  i.e. a class associated with iteself), whereas the second would mean a class associated with nothing (not very useful: any class could be associated with nothing else).

### UML perspective

Fortunately, the UML specifications are much more precise than the common language:

> An Association specifies a semantic relationship that can occur between typed instances. It has **at least two memberEnds** represented by Properties, each of which has the type of the end. **More than one end of the Association may have the same type**.

So in UML there is no "unary association".  It's binary, ternary, or n-ary (terms used in the specs). There is no special term in UML for a binary association with the same class at both ends. But [reflexive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70313142/3723423) or self-association are terms which are more popular than unary.

### E/R modeling

The term "unary" is popular in the context of [entity-relationship modeling](https://www.dlsweb.rmit.edu.au/Toolbox/ecommerce/tbn_respak/tbn_e2/html/tbn_e2_devsol/er_model_relnshps.htm), to describe a relation in a relational database. Relations correspond more or less to an association in UML, and entities to classes, but there are some subtle semantic differences.  E/R has its foundation in the [set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory). And if a relation is between the same entities, it means in fact that only one set is involved. This is probably why unary is more popular in this context.

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam-webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unary) defines Unary as

> having, consisting of, or acting on a single element, item, or
> component

So the first explanation is correct one since this type of association acts on a single class. The term *Unary* however is not used in UML and might be confusing.
UML uses the term **binary** to indicate that an association has two ends, and **ternary** or **n-ary** to indicate an association has multiple ends.
The *Unary* association you are talking about is actually a binary association to itself, also known as **reflexive** association.

[image]

Not to be confused with a *Unidirectional* association, which is an association that is only navigable (has an arrow) to one side.

[image]

Comment: I don't think the first could be claimed to be unary. It's still a binary since it has two ends. Like a sausage (famous German joke song).

Comment: @qwerty_so Yes, but unary seems to be a term sometimes used to describe binary associations to the same class.

Comment: @GeertBellekens the term unary was popular in the ERD context. However it is misleading even there; an analogy to explain why: + is a binary operation, but nobody (I hope) would claim that 1 +1 is a unary operation just because it’s the same number on both sides. In the UML context the term contradicts the specifications (and no single mention of unary there). +1 for the graphical explanations and the disambiguation

Comment: @Christophe Thanks for the input. I've added a bit more explanation about the term Unary.